Evince color management: support for monitor color profile?
I like using Evince for viewing PDF files, it is neither too overloaded nor too simplistic for my taste. But it seems it doesn't have color management. On a modern monitor colors are oversaturated. I'd need support for the monitor color profile. (I don't care about file color profiles, neither color channel conversions like CMYK proofs which will only make the colors look overly dull.) Any suggestions how to achieve that?
